# Код 000-255 в pdf на php

Tags: php, pdf

У меня есть строка кода, которую я получил в xml ответе от удаленного сервера и это нужно конвертировать в PDF файл.
Строка состоит из 3-значных чисел от 000 до 255 и выглядит примерно так:

037
080
068
070
045
049
046
052
... таких 95 000 строчек

Как я могу это сделать при помощи PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ найдено, Если кому то поможет:

```
$string = '037 080 068 070 045 049 046 052 ...';
$dataVals = array();
foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, $string) as $ascii) {
    if(is_numeric($ascii))
        $dataVals []= chr($ascii);
}

$data = implode('', $dataVals);

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону библиотек для генерации PDF файлов. Вот пример: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf . Конкретно эта поддерживается, по ней есть достаточно информации и ответов на том же StackOverflow. В работе и настройке она довольно простая.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) он очень простой + хорошая документация. Также есть хороший пост на [Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/31438/), где описано как использовать на практике fpdf.